# consecutive_find function for returning a consecutive range of elements

Tags: c++, c++11, template, interval

`consecutive_find()` is a function that returns the beginning of a range that contains strictly N consecutive elements. It was part of a SO question that I answered.

Currently this function runs in \$O(n)\$ time. I wanted to know if there are any pitfalls with this function and if it can be improved at all. For example, are there any standard algorithms that can be used here that have not been? [Here is a demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88b3d58b58f7b7c1).

#### Explanation of code:

It sets two variables to the start of the range: `marker` and `lead`. `lead` is always going to be 1 position greater than `marker` (in order to see if there are more consecutive elements).

Then we loop through a count how many elements equal `*lead` using a variable `count`.

It checks `count` to see if it equals `n` (the element count we're looking for) and if either `lead` is the iterator to the end, or if `lead` points to an element that is different than `marker`, then we know that there are no more matching elements that we haven't checked, and we return `marker`, which is `n` places behind `lead`.

If that condition fails, then we know `*lead == *marker`. This goes against the strict condition that we want because there are greater than N consecutive elements. So we set `marker` to the next position that doesn't equal `*lead` to prevent unneeded extra loops. `marker` is set to `lead` and `count` is reset to `1`.

```c++
template <class Iter>
Iter consecutive_find(Iter first, Iter last, std::size_t n)
{
    Iter marker(first), lead(first);
    std::size_t count(1);

    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;

    while (lead != last)
    {
        lead = std::next(marker);
        while ((lead != last) && (*marker == *lead)) { ++count; ++lead; }
        if (count == n)
        {
            if ((lead == last) || !(*lead == *marker))
                return marker;
        }
        marker = std::find_if_not(lead, last,
                                  [&lead] (value_type const& x) { return x == *lead; });
        count = 1;
    }
    return last;
}
```

I can change the nested `while()` loop to [`lead = std::find_if_not(lead, last, \[&lead\] (value_type const& x) { return x == *lead; });`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe877a1eeb91cbd5) but then that violates the DRY rule.

Comment: `if ((lead == last) || !(*lead == *marker))` will always be true so you can remove it.  You know it is true because it is the terminating condition for the while loop that precedes it.  Also, it's not clear to me that you are setting `marker` to the right value with the `find_if_not`.  Shouldn't it just be `marker = lead;`?

Comment: @JS1 I guess the `std::find_if_not` was a remnant from some other version of the code I had. It works find with `marker = lead`.

Comment: @David: can you explain what you mean by "strictly N consecutive". Does `consecutive_find` with `n=2` applied to `std::vector<int>{1 2 2 2 3 3}` yields an iterator pointing to the first `2`, the second `2` or the first `3`?

Comment: @davidhigh It should point to the first `3` because it only contains 2 consecutive elements (strictly 2 consec. elements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function does not work correctly. The bug is in the lines:

```
    marker = std::find_if_not(lead, last,
                              [&lead] (value_type const& x) { return x == *lead; });
```

Say you call the function with the following code:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 2, 2, 3};
auto it = consecutive_find(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);
```

In the function, you start with:

```
marker -> 1
last   -> 1
```

Then, in the first statement of the outer `while` block, you execute:

```
    lead = std::next(marker);
```

Now,

```
last   -> 2
```

You break out of the first inner `while` block with `count` set to `1`, Then you execute

```
    marker = std::find_if_not(lead, last,
                              [&lead] (value_type const& x) { return x == *lead; });
```

When this line is finished executing,

```
marker -> 3
```

and you completely missed the correct return value.

You can change those lines to simply:

```
    marker = lead;
```

and the function works fine.

Here's a sample program and its output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <class Iter>
Iter consecutive_find(Iter first, Iter last, std::size_t n)
{
    Iter marker(first), lead(first);
    std::size_t count(1);

    while (lead != last)
    {
        lead = std::next(marker);
        while ((lead != last) && (*marker == *lead)) { ++count; ++lead; }
        if (count == n)
        {
            if ((lead == last) || !(*lead == *marker))
                return marker;
        }
        marker = lead;
        count = 1;
    }
    return marker;
}

void test1()
{
   std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 2, 2, 3};
   auto it = consecutive_find(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);
   for (int i = 0; i < 3 && it != v.end(); ++i, ++it )
   {
      std::cout << *it << " ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   test1();
}
```

Output:

```
2 2 2
```

Comment: Is the second condition `if ((lead == last) || !(*lead == *marker))` needed?

Comment: No, I don't think you do.

Comment: Is returning `marker` at the end the same returning `last`?

Comment: Definitely not. `last` points to past the end of the vector or past the end of the consecutive elements you are trying to find.